# PowerShell - Insert some characters at the beginning if line contains a string

Tags: powershell

I have a few hundred batch files like this:

```
net use s: \\ukexchange\sysshare 
net use t: \\ukccohelp\helpdesk
net use w: \\ukexchange\public
net use l: \\dwarf\apps
net use y: \\ukexchange\sysgrp
net use k: \\dwarf\sql
```

I want to put a REM in front of each line that contains a string e.g. "ukexchange"

```
REM net use s: \\ukexchange\sysshare 
net use t: \\ukccohelp\helpdesk
REM net use w: \\ukexchange\public
net use l: \\reddwarf\apps
REM net use y: \\ukexchange\sysgrp
net use k: \\dwarf\sql
```

This is what I have, but I have to run this command manually for every combination of UNC path and drive letter.

```
$old = "net use l: \\dwarf\apps"
$new = "REM net use l: \\dwarf\apps"

get-childitem "c:\TEMP\Scripts" -recurse -include *.bat | 
select -expand fullname |
 foreach {
        (Get-Content $_) -replace ("$old" -replace '\\','\\'), "$new" |
         Set-Content $_
        }
```

How can I put some text at the beginning of the line, if somewhere in the line contains a specific string?

Comment: Using a script to managed mapped drives is so 1990s. We no longer need scripts for that. Use a GPO.

Comment: That's exactly my intention, but I need to gradually migrate from 200 logon scripts to GPP drive mappings. I need to migrate one mapped drive at a time, disable it in whichever logon script the drive mapping exists in (multiple logon scripts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to check for the presence of `ukexchange`.

```
$files = get-childitem "c:\TEMP\Scripts" -recurse -include *.bat | select -expand fullname

foreach ($f in $files) {
   $c = Get-Content $f | % { $_ -replace '(.*ukexchange.*)', 'REM $1' }
   $c | Set-Content $f
}
```

If the string is encountered, the whole line is stored into the match group variable `$1`, you can simply prepend `REM` to this

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much! You've saved me hours of work!